# Handling button's click inside input

Tags: javascript, html

I have form, in which I have placed an input - "inside" the input I place a button. The button shows up only when input is focused.

But when I click the button nothing happens.

I was wondering, is it even possible to handle click in such input behaviour?

A secondary problem is to stay focused in this input after click.

https://jsfiddle.net/9btox17j/1/

Adding code here, cause stackoverflow requires it.

```js
const someClickFnc = () => {
    console.log('click!');
};

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', someClickFnc);
```

```css
.input {
  border: none;
  flex: 1;
  width: 100px;
  transition: all, 1s;
}

.input:focus {
  outline: none;
  width: 250px;
}

.input:focus + .input-buttons {
  display: block;
}

.input-wrapper {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 30px;
}

.input-buttons {
  display: none;
}

.button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<form class="input-wrapper">
  <input class="input"/>
  <div class="input-buttons">
    <button class="button">
      Enter
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: As soon as your input field loses focus, the button (resp. the container element it is in), gets `display:none` again. You need to replace this with something, that doesn’t make the button disappear as soon as the input loses focus - if you don’t need IE suport, you can do this by using `:focus-within` on the parent element, to make the button show.

Answer (score 0):

A delay is needed just before focusingout, i dont know if we can manage it using css , but in js way, we can control input by classes.

- When is focused : add a class of `active`
- when unfocused : remove `active` class with a delay.

and in css replace `:focus` with `.active`.

```js
const someClickFnc = (e) => {
 console.log("click!");
 
 // to prevent form submit for now
 e.preventDefault();
};
// the input
let input = document.querySelector('input.input');

// add active class when focused
input.addEventListener('focusin', function(e){
    input.classList.add('active');
});

// remove active class with a 0.5s delay
input.addEventListener('focusout', function(e){
  setTimeout(function(){
    input.classList.remove('active');
  }, 500);
  
});
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', someClickFnc);
```

```css
.input {
  border: none;
  flex: 1;
  width: 100px;
  transition: all, 1s;
}
/* .input:focus changed to .input.active*/
.input.active {
  outline: none;
  width: 250px;
}
/* .input:focus  changed to .input.active*/

.input.active + .input-buttons {
  display: block;
}

.input-wrapper {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 30px;
}

.input-buttons {
  display: none;
}

.button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<form class="input-wrapper">
  <input class="input"/>
  <div class="input-buttons">
    <button class="button">
      Enter
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```